# How do I get access to apport crash logs?

Tags: apport

I develop a program that is available from the official Ubuntu repositories. Is it possible for me to get access to the automatic crash reports (generated with apport) and do I need do implement something in order to collect crash statistics from users?

If it is impossible to get access to Ubuntus own crash logs, am I allowed to collect my own user crash logs?

What is best practice when obtaining crash logs from Ubuntu users?

Comment: Apport crash reports are private by default, and only [Ubuntu bug control members](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBugControl) have access by default. Note "Requirement 4 can be waived if you are an upstream developer"